# Is it possible to get single item SKU details, by single productID?. (Android, IabHelper)

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I want to get single  SKU details (Not ArrayList) using IabHelper, by putting single productID putString() (not putStringArrayList)

```
    ...
    final int API_VERSION = 3;
    final String PACKAGE_NAME = mContext.getPackageName();
    Bundle bandleSKU = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putString(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, "<someProcuctID>"); 
    Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(API_VERSION, PACKAGE_NAME, type, bandleSKU);

    if (null != skuDetails) {
        int response = skuDetails.getInt(RESPONSE_CODE);
        if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
           String response = skuDetails.getString(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);
         }
    }
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this violates the contract of that call. What you should do instead is create a new `ArrayList` of size 1 and add your product ID there:

```
...
Bundle bandleSKU = new Bundle();
ArrayList<String> productIds = new ArrayList<>(1);
productIds.add("<someProductID>");
querySkus.putString(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, productIds); 
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(API_VERSION, PACKAGE_NAME, type, bandleSKU);

if (null != skuDetails) {
    int response = skuDetails.getInt(RESPONSE_CODE);
    if (response == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);
        String productDetailsJson = responseList.get(0);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, I have already did it in this way, as you suggested.
I thought there is a another possible  way to do it.